# h:commandLink conditional target

Tags: java, jsf

I have a `h:commandLink` :

```
<h:commandLink value="" 
    actionListener="#{controller.authenticateAccount}" 
    style="text-decoration: none;" 
    target="#{controller.userNameGiven ? '_parent' : '' }">
        <img src="../images/Profile/authenticateCPButton.gif" border="0" style="padding-left: 2px;"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Now `controller.userNameGiven` is a boolean field and is set to true if username given and otherwise set to false. The `h:commandLink` is present in a iframe and prior to this the `target` was set to `_parent` and then if the username is present then it was redirecting to a page in the same parent window but in other case the iframe was rendered in the parent page which is clearly a bug. Now after the target validation the redirected page is opening in that iframe, which is undesirable. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks and regards.

---

Edit 1:

I have changed the `target` to:

```
target="#{controller.target}"
```

where:

```
    public String getTarget() {
        return target;
    }

    public void setTarget(String target) {
        this.target = target;
    }
```

and

```
if(this.userName != null && this.userName.trim().length()>0) {
            target = "_parent";
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("./somepage");
} else {
            target = "";
}
```

But its still not working and the url somepage is opening in the iframe.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. I think you misspelled "in", "it" and/or "if" as "is" at a few places in the first two sentences below the code snippet. Please review and rectify. As to the concrete problem, is there any particular reason that you're using client-side includes (frames) instead of server-side includes? Using frames is a discouraged technique to compose page parts/templates which originate from the same server as it is not user- nor SEO friendly.

Comment: @BalusC i have edited my post sorry for the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Move the logic into a bean method:

```
public class Controller
{
    // ...

    public boolean isUserNameGiven () { /* snip */ }

    public String getFooTarget()
    {
        return this.isUserNameGiven() ? "_parent" : "";
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm, how did you interpret the question? I tried to re-interpret the question based on your answer, but I failed.

Comment: @Matt Ball I have edited my original post. It's not working :(

Comment: I ignored most of the text and, just based on the code, interpreted the question to be "how can I conditionally set the `target` of the `commandLink` based on the value returned by `controller.userNameGiven`?"

Comment: That EL is valid. I *guess* that the concrete problem boils down to that it's only evaluated when the form is been displayed and not when the form is submitted and validated.